# what javascript pattern is this in mordernizr?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, modernizr

I just went thourgh the http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js

and came across the line no 228

```
_hasOwnProperty = ({}).hasOwnProperty, hasOwnProp;
```

can someone tell me the meaning of this line?

Comment: Good question, it seems to me that `,` should be `||`

Answer (score 6):

This is actually two separate variable declarations. This line is the end of one long `var` statement that starts on the first line of the function. So it's effectively equivalent to:

```
var _hasOwnProperty = ({}).hasOwnProperty;
var hasOwnProp;
```

The first line declares the variable `_hasOwnProperty` and initializes it to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. The second declares the variable `hasOwnProp` without initializing it (the code that follows this sets it to different things depending on whether `_hasOwnProperty` is defined).